# How to create a mask for account Number C#

Tags: string, format, converters, mask

I try to create a mask for a account number, for example:

That I've a function receive an String (11112222334444444444) and I would like to convert to 1111-2222-33-4444444444

```
applyFormatcccc function string (string cccc)
{
   1. myNum string = string.Format ("# # # # - # # # # - # # - # # # # # # # # # #", cccc);
   2. MyNum return;
}
```

but, it's impossible to convert because i put an String (cccc) in the first Line (1).
other case was:

```
double num = 11112222334444444444;
worth num.ToString string = ("# # # # - # # # # - # # - # # # # # # # # # #", num)
```

it's the result: `11112222334444400000 -> only accept 8 bytes`

How is the best form to use Apply this mask without an loops (for, while) .. as far as possible

Comment: Please read the [Editing-Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to format the code in your post.

Comment: Oh...Sorry. Using C#. thanks. I change the tittle..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Ajax markededitor extender for this.

eg :

< asp:TextBox
ID = "TextBox1"
runat = "server"
ForeColor = "HotPink"
>

< cc1:MaskedEditExtender
ID = "MaskedEditExtender1"
runat = "server"
TargetControlID = "TextBox1"
Mask = "9999-9999-99-9999999999"
MaskType = "Number"
MessageValidatorTip = "true"
>

Comment: I tried to go for Ajax, but the problem is:

I have a grid where I want the client name +  </ br>) + the account number is displayed.

as the property receives a String,so I can not apply formatting directly